# Multiple randomly chosen cells with specified odds

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Say I have five cells each containing names:

```
John
Elias
Bertrand
Jenny
Claris
```

And I want to randomly pick one of them - but with the caveat that the odds for each of them is different - ie. John should be picked 30% of the time, Elias 10%, Bertrand 5%, Jenny 40% and Claris 15%.
How can I achieve this? I understand rand() can pick a random number. But I fail to see how I can convert it to be specified to these odds and then show the random name. A workaround in this case could be to make 20 rows of the names and then choose a random cell - each representing 5% odds - but there must be a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your names are in A1:A5

```
=LOOKUP(100*RAND(),{0;30;40;45;85},A1:A5)
```

I'm not 100% sure, but this seems like it would work for your problem.

Lookup works by finding the item in a sorted array that's closest to the value you're looking up, but without being MORE than that value. sort of like The Price is Right rules.

in this case a anything between 0 and .2999999999 would return whatever is in A1.  anything between .3 and .399999999 would return whatever is in A2, etc.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks a lot <3